# How to get multiple result only with array_agg in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select title, count(1), program.program_type, channel.name as channel_name, array_agg(distinct program_title.program_id) as programId
    from program 
join program_title 
    on program.program_id = program_title.program_id
join schedule
    on program.program_id = schedule.program_id
join channel
    on channel.channel_id = schedule.channel_id
group by program_title.title, program.program_type, channel.name
having count(1) > 1
```

I put the sql query like this.
And I could get this output

```
|title  | count | program_type | channel_name | programid |
|Title1 | 2     | movie        | channel1     | {1234}    |
|Title2 | 6     | movie        | channel2     | {5432435} |
```

The count would be the number of programid.
Because I put distinct option.

How to I show the columns only it has multiple programID?
Like this

```
|title  |count | program_type | channel_name | programid    |
|Title1 |    2 | movie        | channel1     | {1234, 5533} |
```

I want to get only records that have multiple programID values ​​that are not duplicates.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: are you aware that `count(1)` is actually [_slower_](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/09/19/whats-faster-count-or-count1/) than `count(*)`

Comment: @wooggumoggu : You should show your table and your required out put.

Comment: The query you have seems to do what you want. If you don't get multiple values for programid, then there aren't multiple values - maybe you need to remove  `channel_name` from the `group by`?

Comment: A "distinct" inside an aggregate applies just to that aggregate.  If you want a separate aggregate to count distinct values, you must write it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want another condition in the `having` clause:

```
having count(*) > 1 and count(distinct programid) > 1
```

Actually, these two conditions are redundant, so this is equivalent:

```
having count(distinct programid) > 1
```

`count(distinct)` can be slow.  One alternative is:

```
having min(programid) <> max(programid)
```